# Kotlin Flow collect takes a long time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I have a local database in my Android app. There is a function that takes some data from server and updates local database.
When this function is running, if I collect a list from local database by returning Flow, it takes unusual time to finish.
I don't have any problem with LiveData, it works well but Flow doesn't.

this is my dao :

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=:id")
fun getData(id: String): Flow<Entity?>
```

repo :

```
    fun getData(id: String): Flow<Entity?> {
    return dao.getData(id).map { it?.toModel() }
}
```

fragment :

```
lifecycleScope.launch() {

        repo.getData(args.id)
            .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .collect { data ->

                data?.let {
                    setData(data)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the LiveData version of this code for comparison? Could the difference simply be the `distinctUntilChanged()`?

Comment: What do you mean by saying it takes a lot of time to finish? I'm not very familiar with Room, so I may be entirely wrong, but I believe `collect()` in this case is expected to actually never finish. It waits for changes in the DB. Or maybe you mean you never get to the `setData()` line?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I tried to remove distinctUntilChanged line but it's the same. also I tried to use collectLatest and again problem is present

Comment: @broot It takes an unusual time to get data in collect lambda (about 3 seconds). Actually it waits to my modifications to database be finished and after that it gives me the data

Comment: How could it not have to wait for the data to be put in the database before getting the new values from the database? I can't understand why using LiveData would be any different.

Comment: @Tenfour04 no idea

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) in you repository function after map like this:

**Repository**

```
fun getData(id: String): Flow<Entity?> {
    return dao.getData(id)
            .map { it?.toModel() }
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

I think the problem is that you delay the main thread with your heavy function operation (map) on the flow.

Comment: This is false. A DAO flow does not block the main thread. You can use any upstream dispatcher and it will make no difference except for which thread `toModel()` is called on (and that sounds like it's probably a trivial conversion).

Comment: Correct but in repository function is a map operation on flow

Comment: He should definitely use flowOn this is best programming practice, ok this doesn't block main thread but is still heavy operation (map)

Comment: If the flow type was a large list so there was a nested map operation, I’d agree, but it’s a single class instance being converted. You’d almost certainly be adding more overhead with your thread switching and continuation manipulation (under the hood of flowOn) than the operation itself costs. Regardless, the OP’s stated issue is how long it takes, not that the main thread is acting janky.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: @Tenfour04 My entity is a relational entity that consists from 3 other simple entity.
As you said my data isn't a huge data and also I don't have any problem when I use LiveData instead of Flow, so do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: OK, try to remove distinctUntilChanged(), in your use case isn't necessary, .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect {
                 
                }